# Public shp file showing Berlin subway entrances?

Tags: shapefile, data, transit, germany

I was inspired by someone else's work to try finding the Berlin property farthest from a subway station. In order to do that, I will need two things:

First, I need a shapefile of all the building addresses in Berlin. I believe I have found this here:
http://opendata.esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/d4ac5d6ff99140819d2033038664096c_0

**I will also need a shapefile showing all the subway (U-Bahn) entrances in Berlin. Does anyone know of such a shapefile?**

Bonus heaps of gratitude will come your way if you can dig up a shapefile of S-Bahn stations as well, though this is not strictly necessary. Note that I am looking for the entrances/stations, rather than the lines themselves.

Assuming I can locate a shapefile showing U-Bahn lines, I will be doing my analysis using python and QGIS. Here is the original inspiration for this project:

http://iquantny.tumblr.com/post/99544282749/found-the-manhattan-apartment-thats-the-farthest

Comment: I think this question may be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange where there are questions like http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/966/are-there-public-transport-data-for-germany-freely-available

Comment: I figured I should close the loop on this. Here is a github repository that includes code to calculate the Haversine distance from each Berlin property to its nearest subway entrance.  

https://github.com/patrickmaynard/playing-with-berlin-subways

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) which can locate subway entrances in Berlin. You can [click here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jqV) to see the results or type the following query in the Overpass command box:

```
node
  [railway=subway_entrance]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

---

Example:

[image: Overpass Turbo]

To extract the data, click the **Extract** button and choose the file type (I chose .kml):

[image: Export data]

You can then load the exported data into your GIS software:

[image: Result]

Comment: With the QuickOSM plugin, you get the Overpass results directly into QGIS as a points shapefile or geojson layer. Note that the kml format might loose some attributes.

Comment: @Patrick - Most welcome =)